# How to set password encryption to SSHA in OpenLDAP C code API?

Tags: c++, c, passwords, openldap, ssha

So I'm writing C++ code that wraps OpenLDAP's C code to set up a basic client controller (so I can connect to a server, view users, etc.).

Whenever I add a new user though, the password gets encrypted as `{CRYPT}` but I need it as `{SSHA}`. There also doesn't appear to be a way to just input a plain password (as in, encrypt it yourself and then put it in). It always encrypts it into `{CRYPT}`. I was told that OpenLDAP supports `{SSHA}`.

I'm using the following code to set the password when adding a new user:

```cpp
passVals[0] = passwordC;
passVals[1] = NULL;
char passwordT[] = "userPassword";
passMod.mod_op = 0;
passMod.mod_type = passwordT;
passMod.mod_vals.modv_strvals = passVals;
```

Where `passVals` is `char*`, `passMod` is `LDAPMod*`, `passwordT` is the name of the attribute for the password, and `passwordC` is the user password (in this case just a simple test password called "newPassword").

`passMod` is then passed into an `LDAPMod**` that handles all the user attributes, which I then pass into `ldap_add_ext_s(...)`. This works for everything except the user password, which doesn't encrypt right.

Expected output:

> {SSHA} <string of characters/numbers here>

Actual output:

> {CRYPT}$6$y63RUAlxygdasWNT$jh3.QRVtQT9nCRyjo6cFlGFimHCyUFRwdLk6wqZTCZh1JKWTB35at0M/aghuCul9GaCbzowkm6YfPZkGKhgiW/

I can't find any options or functions to change this. The same issue happens when I update the password of an existing user with `ldap_extended_operation(...)`, even if the original password was `{SSHA}`.

Any help is appreciated. I'm also okay with a solution that involves just setting the password as plain text (not auto encrypting), as I could encrypt it myself elsewhere. The problem is that it always forces the wrong encryption no matter what.

Comment: Why does this have both the [tag:c] and [tag:c++] tags? Your question body says this is c++ code, so I think you should [edit] to remove the [tag:c] tag.

Comment: Because I'm wrapping C code in C++, so it's both and both sets of rules need to be applied, such as how the C side functions cannot take regular strings.

Comment: Oh dear I should have read carefully before commenting! Sorry about that. Thanks for the explanation. I'll be more careful in the future.

Comment: The password encryption scheme must be defined on the server, you can apply it to slapd configuration using `olcPasswordHash` (or `password-hash` in old slapd.conf mode). See this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/571928/how-do-you-set-password-hash-for-openldap).